# How call function inside another function Firebase function ionic 5

Tags: node.js, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-functions

I have the following method

```
export const teste = functions.database.ref('teste/{id}/').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
   call dailyJob()
});
```

how can I call the next function after insert data

```
export const dailyJob = functions.pubsub
.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun(context => {
   console.log('This will be run every day at 5:30AM');
});
```

Comment: This might be clearer if you just explain what you're trying to achieve? Is it some kind of conditional cloud function deployment?

Comment: I want to create a function to schedule a event

Comment: the teste function listen when some data added in database, then dailyJob create a schedule function

Comment: Do you mean, when a `teste` document is created, you want to schedule a new function? And schedule yet, regular-interval another function for each `teste` document that's added??

Comment: I have in firebase the following structure 
{uid}
   - power = 0
   - on = 08:00
   - off = 14:00
   days = 0,1

Comment: when this data is created with day and time, then we call function to schedule

Comment: It might be more practicable to manually deploy a `pubsub` scheduled function that checks your database for some kinda flag. That flag would be updated inside your handler for `teste` document `onCreate`

Comment: Using a Pub/Sub trigger - which you can schedule - is the best option, as @JayCodist mentioned. You won't be able to achieve what you want, without at least, a third application helping you. Could you please check [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub) and verify if following the tutorial with Pub/Sub helps you? In case it doesn't, please, share more information on how you are planning to try or is trying to achieve your goal.